# Javascript Check Login function returns false, but continues to next line anyways?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

The following code checks for a user and returns false if the user is not logged in.

```
  function checkLogin(e) {
    loggedIn = $('#loggedin').text();
    if(loggedIn == '1'){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Please Log In");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I then call this function before some other code and an ajax call.

```
tileFavorite = $('.tileFavorite');
tileFavorite.on('click', function(e) {
      checkLogin(e);

     //some code goes here before ajax call

    $.ajax({
        url: // ajax call goes here,
        cache: false
    })
});
```

The check login actually works. However if the checkLogin function returns false, it still continues to the code beneath it. There a way to avoid this?

Comment: That's because the return false is for checkLogin function. But your click function of tileFavorite is still executing since it have not reached a return yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing to prevent that code from being called.

Try:

```
  function checkLogin(e) {
    loggedIn = $('#loggedin').text();
    if(loggedIn == '1'){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Please Log In");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

tileFavorite.on('click', function(e) {
    if (! checkLogin(e))
      return false;

     //some code goes here before ajax call

    $.ajax({
        url: // ajax call goes here,
        cache: false
    })
});
```

Comment: Yea, perfect, it makes perfect sense. Kind of a "duh" moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tileFavorite.on('click', function(e) {
  if(false == checkLogin(e)){
    return false;
  }
     //some code goes here before ajax call

    $.ajax({
        url: // ajax call goes here,
        cache: false
    })
});
```

tileFavorite on click should return value to stop execution.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, a little too late!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't doing anything with the `false` that is actually returned.  You could try:

```
if (checkLogin(e)) {
    ...
    $.ajax(
        ...
    );
}
```